# Is defining variables for every condition is better then using getter and setters?

Tags: java

I have two codes can anyone tell me which approach is the better and why.

**Approach 1 -**

```
if (("Male").equalsIgnoreCase(input.getSex()) || ("Female").equalsIgnoreCase(input.getSex())) {
    // do something
}else{
   //do somethong
}
```

**Approach 2 -**

```
String tempSex = input.getSex()
if (("Male").equalsIgnoreCase(tempSex) || ("Female").equalsIgnoreCase(tempSex)) {
    // do something
}else{
    //do somethong
}
```

this is one condition, in my code, I have a lot of conditions similar to this one. In some condition, I have to compare with a lot more Strings.

Is this a good approach to define variables for every condition or I can use getter and setters?

Comment: Well, the first and the second approaches would result in totally different outputs.

Comment: @progy_rock Please explain how - if you are referring to side effects you could have helped the OP by explaining.

Comment: output of both the approach are same. I want to know about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

These two approaches are essentially identical in terms of performance assuming the getSex function is a trivial getter (if getSex is complex or involves changing some other state in the class then these two bits of code are NOT equivalent).

I would prefer the first from a style point of view in that the extra local variable is slightly confusing to the flow of the code.

However if you main purpose is using code of this form is to validate legal input (as it appears from your example) I would try to create a method
`boolean input.isSexValid()` to encapsulate that functionality which would make the code less repetitive and more readable.

Comment: The two approaches are quite different. If the 'getSex()` method has side effects, or could possibly return different values each time it's called, then the results will differ. We don't know enough about the method to answer the question. So if you did answer it, absent that knowledge, ...

Comment: @LewBloch I specifically mention the restrictions on the nature of getSex() in the first paragraph.

Comment: Consider that I was emphasizing the dangers of when those restrictions do not apply, given that the OP might not fully appreciate that. But yes, you did mention that those restrictions are necessary for equivalence. I called out details of how they differ when the restrictions do not apply. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score -1):

Strong argument that this is primarily opinion based, but:

I vote Approach 2.

What if the getter is slow (like it has to go to a DB)? You have a redundant round trip to the DB.

Comment: There are actually engineering reasons why one or the other idiom might suit better, so it really isn't so much a matter of opinion. Both approaches are valid in various circumstances, but not equally valid in all circumstances. You can evaluate that validity objectively.